# JavaScript dynamic graph library for displaying "big-data"?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, graph, d3.js, data-visualization

What's the name of this graph (see image)? - Also, is there a JavaScript library which supports generation and dynamic traversal for such a graph?

[image: graph from Google]

Answer (score 4):

It could be something like a node-link tree. There are a few examples with D3 that look similar [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550), [here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) and [here](http://thepowerrank.com/visual/NCAA_Tournament_Predictions). Whether this is suitable for "big data" depends entirely on your definition of "big data".